# use word printout in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, com

I'm using PHP COM to manipulate msword.

```
$word->PrintOut(false, empty, empty, empty, empty,....);
```

Some parameters/varables are "optional", but can't be set as null or "" or 0

Will throw error: **Parameter 16: Type not match** (translated)

I found someone using "**System.Reflection.Missing.Value**"  in **C#**   ("empty/not set")

but, how can I use this in PHP? or something simillar.

thanks

I want to use **PrintOut** in php with parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up again.

**use vba macro** instead,and **call it in php**, put parameter after with ,

```
$word->run('macro_to_printout', $copies);
```

in word

```
sub macro_to_printout(copies as integer)

...

end sub
```

more vba help than this, don't waste you time on php com